# How to retrieve data using a SQL query that takes a list of users stored in a powershell variable as input?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a list of Ids in the $netid variable from the below powershell script:

```
$netid =Get-ADGroupMember ADGROUPSAMPLE1 | select accountname
```

Which stores the following in the variable:

```
accountname
===========
User1
User2
User3
```

I have a SQL Server database table which has mapping between the netid and their workstation name.

```
User  |Machinename
------------------
User1 |laptop1 
User2 |laptop2 
User3 |laptop3
```

I'm new to powershell and thus need help with a powershell script that can help me pull the laptop names from the database for all the ids stored in the $netid variable. SQL Server version is SQL Server 2014.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

Since one can use .NET objects in PowerShell, SqlClient may be used to execute a parameterized query. The example below converts the account list to json and uses [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) (available in SQL 2016 and later) to parse the json list for the join to the users table. With older SQL versions, you caan similarly convert the list to XML and use XML methods to parse the XML parameter in T-SQL.

```
$netid = Get-ADGroupMember ADGROUPSAMPLE1 | select accountname

$accountList = $netid | ConvertTo-Json

$sql = @"
SELECT UserTable.[User], UserTable.MachineName
FROM OPENJSON(@AccountList)
WITH(
    AccountName nvarchar(30) '$.accountname'
) AS AccountList
JOIN dbo.UserTable ON UserTable.[User] = AccountList.AccountName;
"@

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql, $connection)
$sqlDataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command)
$command.Parameters.Add("@AccountList", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1).Value = $accountList
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$sqlDataAdapter.Fill($dataTable)
$dataTable | Out-GridView
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: I tried the above script but it only returns the User name. It doesn't return the Machinename

Comment: The MachineName value returned by the query comes from the UserTable and only for accounts that exist in the table and the account list. Verify you have MachineName values for the users returned in dbo.UserTable.